# fopen write with variable issue

Tags: php

small project - stumped typing to get it working - if you have any ideas please let me know tku! This post program is requiring more words so here we go

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("issue-heads-1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {        

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {

            if ($row == 2) {
            $file = fopen($data[14], "w");
            $write = '
            <?php
                include "/home/history/public_html/issue1.php";
                echo \'<a class="prev" href="\' . $data[16] . \'">\';
            ?>
            ';
            fwrite($file, $write);
            fclose($file);
            }
        $num = count($data);

        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please explain more about your problem since there is not much context to work with.

Comment: have php web page template and need to use it to create hundreds more for a library. I have  csv file I am pulling data from to insert into the template and each file then saved. The echo statement in the write statement isn't working - it doesn't understand the variable.

Comment: Are your CSV headers unique?

Comment: Hi Curious - following up again. Thank you for providing an answer that shows how you solved the problem. Reminding you to please choose your own answer as "Best Answer" by clicking the checkmark beside the answer. That will close out this question. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a variable inside a write statement didn't work while inside a fopen statement. I ended up having to use ob_start to get it to work. Hat tip to gibberish for getting me on the right path.

```
<?php

ob_start();
include 'issue1.php';
$issueone = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("issue-heads-1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {  
            $csv[] = $data;
        }
    fclose($handle);
    }       
        $file = fopen($csv[$row][14], "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            fwrite($file, $issueone);
            fwrite($file, "<a class=\"prev\" href=\"" . $csv[$row][16] . "\">");
        fclose($file);

print "ok";

?>
```

Comment: Good morning - glad you got it solved, and thanks for letting us know how you solved it. +1

Answer (score 1):

Quick guess - Try (untested):

```
        $write = '
        <?php
            include "/home/history/public_html/issue1.php";
            echo \'<a class="prev" href="' . $data[16] . '">\';
        ?>
        ';
```

It's just a bit tricky with the multiple quotes... think you might have lost track of which ones need escaping...

Hmmmm... so that didn't work... the next thing I would try is to construct the $write variable over several lines (hopefully making the job a bit easier, so perhaps easier to avoid error) - note that I also threw in a repeating filewrite to see what the output is:

```
$hF = fopen('__debug.log', "a"); //outside your loop

//inside loop
$hrf = $data[16];
$write = '<?php' + "\n";
$write .= 'include "/home/history/public_html/issue1.php";' + "\n";
$write .= "echo '<a class=\"prev\" href=\"";
$write .= $hrf;
$write .= "\">';" + "\n";
$write .= '?>';
fwrite($hF, $write);
```

and make sure to close the file before your script ends:

```
//outside the loop
fclose($hF);
```

Comment: great try - output was: <a class="prev" href=""> <== href empty. When I print $data[16] above the write statement I see the url ok so I know the data is in the variable. I'm guessing I need to pass the variable's contents to the write statement somehow.

Comment: Added another couple of suggestions... perhaps one of these low-tech razors will do the trick, helping you to identify the error - following which you can refactor your code to be structured as you truly want it. *(Again all my code is off-the-cuff so please double-check syntax etc)*

Comment: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/history/public_html/lemon.php on line 12

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/history/public_html/lemon.php on line 12

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/history/public_html/lemon.php on line 13

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/history/public_html/lemon.php on line 13

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/history/public_html/lemon.php on line 16

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/history/public_html/lemon.php on line 16

Comment: lines 12-16

$write = '<?php' + "\n";
$write .= 'include "/home/history/public_html/issue1.php";' + "\n";
$write .= "echo '<a class=\"prev\" href=\"";
$write .= $hrf;
$write .= "\">';" + "\n";

Comment: debug log: 00echo '<a class="prev" href="0?>

Comment: you got data[16] to  produce - good job! The separate write statements seemed to be the trick. fwrite($hF, $write); isn't writing anything in the $data[14] file though - I'll have to keep working this

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique headers in your CSV

```
$headers = [];

while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($handle))) {
     if(empty($headers)){
          $headers = $data;  //["foo", "bar"] (for example)
          continue; //skip to next iteration
     }
      //$data [1,2] (for example)

     $row = array_combine($headers, $data);

     //$row = ["foo"=>1,"bar"=>2] (for example)

}
```

Now you can use the text headers instead of `16` etc...

One thing to be careful of is array combine is very sensitive to the length of the arrays.  That said if it errors you either have duplicate keys (array keys are unique) or you have either an extra `,` or a missing one for that line.

Array combine takes the first argument as the keys, and the second as the values and combines them into an associative array.  This has the added benefit that the order of your CSV columns will not be important (which can be a big deal).

**PS** as I have no idea what your headers are, I will leave that part up to you.  But lets say `#16` is `issues`.  Now you can simply do `$row['issues']` just like a DB source etc...

Cheers.

Comment: Kool, - you can also use SplFileObject for reading CSV if you want a more Object oriented API to work with.  It also keeps track of what line you are on etc...